# while(<@array>) effects for perl

Tags: perl, while-loop

```
while(<@thisArray>)
```

Does anyone know what this would do exactly?  We were just having a discussion on it as it's the code is usually something like:

```
while(<STDIN>)
```

Comment: It's not supposed to do anything, as `@array` is not a filehandle name, it's the name of an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<@thisArray>` works as `glob(@thisArray)`. So it gives a list of all files matching the members of the array.

If an element of the array doesn't match a file, the element itself is returned.

Answer (score 10):

It'll iterate through files names matched to patterns in `@thisArray`.

Result of `perl -MO=Deparse -e '1 while(<@thisArray>)'` shows that `<>` is converted to [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
use File::Glob ();
'???' while defined($_ = glob(join($", @thisArray)));
```

From [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) manual:

> In scalar context, glob iterates through such filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.

Default value for `$"` is space, therefore multiple patterns from `@thisArray` will be joined into single string and then splitted back by space inside `glob`:

> Note that glob splits its arguments on whitespace and treats each segment as separate pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was using it for a count so the count would've been way off.

Answer (score 5):

See [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators):

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a
>   simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or
>   typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be
>   globbed